# docker is not running django server

Tags: django, docker, sqlite, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I'm trying to host a django project in docker. I tried to follow the tutorial from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database) but instead of postgresql, I use sqlite. I tried to run `docker-compose up` but docker was stuck at this: 
[image]

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

and my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: spartakode/sqlite3:latest
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: Your db fails and exits

Comment: do you know why? I can't find any guide on how to use sqlite with django and docker online

Answer (score 0):

You have not mounted any database inside sqlite image. The [readme](https://hub.docker.com/r/spartakode/sqlite3/) of the sqlite repository says to mount the database at `/db/db.db` inside container.

You can do this by including volumes in the `docker-compose.yml` file. Your new file should look like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: spartakode/sqlite3:latest
    volumes:
      - ./database.db:/db/db.db
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but it returned 'error: unable to open database db.db: unable to open database file exited with code 1'. I also tried to change db.db to db.sqlite3 and it still exited with code 0

Comment: I think that you need to have an existing database file in the base directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is a local database file that python/django writes to directly, not a remote database server you can connect to.

- For postgres, you'd use a separate postgres docker and you'd have `'HOST': 'db'` in your `DATABASES` setting.
- For sqlite, you'd just have `'NAME': 'localfilename.db'` in your `DATABASES` setting. sqlite support is build right into python, so you don't need any additional packages .

  In your case, it means you can remove the entire `db` service from your `docker-compose.yml`, leaving only the `web` service.

Note: if you use sqlite in a docker, you should make sure the actual database file is stored somewhere on a volume, otherwise the file is lost when your docker stops. In your case you're fine, because you've mounted the current directory as `/code` in your `docker-compose.yml`. The db file will be `/code/localfilename.db` inside your docker and just `localfilename.db` inside your local development directory.

For reference, your `settings.py` ought to include something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': 'localfilename.db'},
}
```